# AJAX post with spring mvc controller doesn't work 406 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have searched the whole internet for a solution and nothing works.
I keep receiving the 406 - Not Acceptable error when I try to post a course-object with ajax.

**Description of the error:**

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

The weird thing is that the second time I send the request I get a 500 -> The "course" already exists. So the object is saved at the server side.

**The ajax request:**

```
function addCourse() {
var name = $('#course_name').val();
var sp = $('#course_sp').val();
var h_sp = $('#course_hour_sp').val();
var student_id = $('#studentID').val();

var information = {studentId: student_id, name: name, studyPoints: sp, 
hoursPerStudyPoint: h_sp, studiedHours:"00:00:00"};

$.ajax({
    url: "studentView/addCourse.htm",
    data: JSON.stringify(information),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#course_name').val("");
        $('#course_sp').val("");
        $('#course_hour_sp').val("");

        addNewCourse(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
}
```

**The controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/studentView")
public class CoursesController {

private final Service service;

@Autowired
public CoursesController(Service service){
    this.service = service;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addCourse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Course createCourse(@RequestBody Course course) throws 
DatabaseException{
    service.addCourse(course);
    return course;
}
}
```

**POM dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>productive-studying-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to add `consumes="application/json"` to your RequestMapping

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Please change to @RequestBody String course and see how it goes. This is just to see whether the problem is on the binding. If it is goes ok, sysout the course and see the content if it is valid JSON. Use this site to check the JSON https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: OMG you were absolutely right!!! 
I used the ObjectMapper to convert course to JSON and I returned the json as String. Everything worked perfectly. Such a stupid mistake.. 
I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

you are using `url: "studentView/addCourse.htm",` into ajax code, you need to use 'url: "studentView/addCourse",' into code, remove `.htm` from url.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but the problem was the JSON ;) I forgot farsterxml jackson doesn't automatically transform the object to json but instead you have to use the ObjectMapper. Stupid mistake.